# Remove numbers from list, if not contained in substring of other list

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply, psql

Here's my situation:

I have one list of product names such as:
`BLUEAPPLE, GREENBUTTON20, 400100DUCK20` (len = 9000)
and a list of official item names such as:
`BLUEAPPLE, GREENBUTTON, 100DUCK`. (len = 2700)

As I'll be applying fuzzy string matching to product - items, I want to strip away the unnecessary numbers from the product names -- but keep numbers that are represented in official item names.

I came up with a solution, but the issue is it works *very* slowly.

```
def remove_nums(product):
    if bool(re.search('\d'), product):
        for item in item_nums_list:
            if item in product_name:
                substrings = [u for x in product_name.split(item) for u in (x, item)][:-1]
                no_num_list = [re.sub('(\d+)', '', substring) if substring not in item else substring for substring in substrings]
                return ''.join(no_num_list)
        return re.sub('(\d+)', '', product)
    else:
        return product
```

Example:

```
product_name = '400100DUCK20'
item = '100DUCK'
substrings = ['400','100DUCK','20']
no_num_list = ['','100OG','']
returns '100DUCK'
```

This function is mapped so that it's looping over every product in the product list.

I've been trying to figure out a way to use lambdas here, maps, applys, etc, but can't quite wrap my head around it. What would be the most *efficient* way to accomplish what I am trying to do, either with straight lists, or in pandas? Alternatively, I'm getting these item and product lists from a postgres database, so if you think it'd be faster to do in psql I'd go that route.

Comment: Given your example, why don't you just return `item`

Comment: Unfortunately, due to the nature of the of the products and items I'm matching, returning item results in a lot of false positives. For example:
`COLA100` (product) would match with `A10` (official item) when in reality they shouldn't have been matched. Fuzzy string matching that I apply later would hopefully correct this.

Answer (score 1):

[`difflib.get_close_matches()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) will at least help clean up your code and will probably run faster.

```
import difflib
p_names = ['BLUEAPPLE', 'GREENBUTTON20', '400100DUCK20']
i_names = ['BLUEAPPLE', 'GREENBUTTON', '100DUCK']
for p in p_names:
    print(difflib.get_close_matches(p, i_names))

>>> 
['BLUEAPPLE']
['GREENBUTTON']
['100DUCK']
>>>
```

There are still going to be a lot of comparisons taking place, it has to match every string in p_names to every string in i_names.

---

Similar to your approach using a regular expressions to find a match:

```
import re
for p in p_names:
    for i in i_names:
        if re.search(i, p):
            print(i)
            # stop looking
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def remove_nums(product):
    if re.search('\d', product):
        for item in item_nums_list:
            if item in product:
                return item
        return re.sub('(\d+)', '', product)
else:
    return product
```

Also, make sure you are using the normal python interpreter.  IPython and other interpreters with debugging features are a LOT slower than the regular interpreter.

You might want to consider doing some set operations first though.  Here's a little example:

```
product_set = set(product_list)
item_number_set = set(item_number_list)

# these are the ones that match straight away
product_matches = product_set & item_number_set

# now we can search through the substrings of ones that don't match
non_matches = product_set - item_number_set
for product in non_matches:
    for item_number in item_number_set:
        if item_number in product:
            product_matches.add(product)
            break

# product_matches is now a set of all unique codes contained in both lists by "fuzzy match"
print(product_matches)
```

You kind of lose the order in which they appeared, but maybe you can find a way to modify this for your use.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't just return 'item' if the item is in the product name. And I do get rid of exact matches before starting this process, so I need to find a different way to optimize.